# Modulus and Bound Problem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

If $z_0$, $z_1$ $\in B(0,\epsilon)$ where $B(0,\epsilon)$ is a subset of $\mathbf{C}$. Under what condition on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $\frac{\alpha+z_0}{\beta z_1+z_0}$ would be in $B(0,\epsilon)$?

That is, if $|z_0|<\epsilon$ and $|z_1|<\epsilon$, under what condition on $\alpha$ and $\beta$, $|\frac{\alpha+z_0}{\beta z_1+z_0}|<\epsilon$ ?

Note that, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and $z_0$ and $z_{1}$ are all complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is the following:

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given.
>   For what $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb C$ does the following hold:
>   $$
>  \left|\frac{\alpha+z_0}{\beta z_1+z_0}\right|<\epsilon \quad \text{ for all }
>  z_0, z_1 \in \mathbb C \text{ with }
>  |z_0|<\epsilon \text{ and } |z_1|<\epsilon \, .
> $$

First let us assume that $\beta \ne 0$. Then we can choose
$$
  z_0 = \frac \beta n \, , \quad z_1 = -\frac 1n
$$
where $n$ is so large that $|z_0|<\epsilon$ and $|z_1|<\epsilon$.
Then $\beta z_1+z_0 = 0$ so that the fraction becomes infinite.

So $\beta$ must be zero and the fraction reduces to
$$
\frac{\alpha+z_0}{z_0} 
$$
which is infinite if $z_0 = 0$ and $\alpha \ne 0$.

Therefore $\alpha = \beta = 0$, which is a (trivial) solution
only if $\epsilon > 1$. For $\epsilon \le 1$ there is no solution at all.